Why is the Send Tracking Click Activity with an ampscript link different than the clicks tracked for that link's alias?
The link for the logo in my email is assigned with ampscript %%=redirectTo(@logo)=%% but the link also has an alias of "Logo" assigned to it. In the send tracking, click activity for the alias "Logo" shows 50 unique clicks but click activity for %%=redirectTo(@logo)=%% is showing 8234 unique clicks. If the 8234 clicks are spam filters, why wouldn't the alias "Logo" register those clicks as well?
Additional info: When looking at the info associated with the %%=redirectTo(@logo)=%% clicks, all clicks occurred within an hour of sending.
